# How to find a direction in real space that corresponds to a vector in reciprocal space

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

Having cell parameters one can compute reciprocal lattice parameters and then both metric tensors.
Everything I did from that point on was either in direct or reciprocal space.
I'm however out of my mathematical depth when it comes to question how to re-calculate a direction in direct space to one in reciprocal and vice versa.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hm, what do you mean by "corresponds", exactly? Primitive vectors ${\bf t}_i$ and their dual vectors ${\bf g}_j$ are linked by ${\bf t}_i\cdot{\bf g}_j=2\pi\delta_{ij}$. So would for you ${\bf g}_1$ "correspond" to ${\bf t}_1$ and you are asking how to calculate t's from g's and vice versa, or? Anyway in general vectors in the reciprocal space identity planes in the real space (think about waves and phase planes, for instance), rather than specific directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently one need only to multiply the metric tensor with the vector.

I'm embarrassed...